# Converting *.adf files to *.xyz for XPSWMM?

Tags: convert, qgis-2, tiles, raster-conversion, esri-grid-format

i am trying to convert adf files to xyz files in order to import them to XPSWMM.  i also need the elevation values.  however, when i use QGIS to translate the raster files (adf files) to xyz these errors show up,

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/Mark.Valiente/.qgis2/python/plugins\BLNExporter\BLNExp.py",
>   line 208, in EnablePlugin
>       if (layer.geometryType() == QGis.Polygon) or (layer.geometryType() == QGis.Line) or (layer.geometryType() == QGis.Point): AttributeError: 'QgsRasterLayer' object has no attribute 'geometryType'

and it says,

> Warning 6: A dataset opened by GDALOpenShared should have the same
>   filename (H:\DEM\Tiles_1kmx1km\e492161301001\w001001.adf) and
>   description (H:\DEM\Tiles_1kmx1km\e492161301001)

when the conversion has finished only a solid black color was displayed on the work area.

here are the names and formats in every folder of the directory,

```
dblbnd.adf
hdr.adf
metadata.xml
prj.adf
sta.adf
w001001.adf
w001001x.adf
```

Comment: They are Esri GRID raster format, did you copy the folder/files in explorer? if so you have broken the GRID most likely, it should be in a folder (don't rename) next to an info folder (an ArcInfo workspace) try GDAL_Translate -of xyz see http://www.gdal.org/1.11/frmt_xyz.html to convert into ASCII XYZ format.

Comment: yes, i copied the folders in another drive. how must i copy the files without breaking them?

Comment: You can copy the whole workspace in explorer but not the GRID folder. You cannot rename the folder or put it into a path more than 128 characters deep see http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009t0000000w000000 abut the Esri GRID raster format.